Can a MK2B heat bed fit on a mk42 carriage plate
I’m making my first diy Prusa i3 mk2 and have no luck with finding a mk42 heatbed clone and am wondering if a MK2B heat plate could fit on the mk42 carriage

The MK42 is a Prusa design (Prusa i3 MK2 and MK2S (frame, Y carriage)) so the dimensions should be somewhere published in the original DXF files from Prusa. You can also look up the drawings of the MK2B holes to compare that against each other.
